# Guards en Angular: CanMatchFn y CanActivateFn

Tags: angular, angular-router

estoy haciendo un curso de Angular y tengo un problema con CanMatch y CanActivate porque estan deprecados y ahora se reemplazan con CanMatchFn y CanActivateFn que son funciones. El problema es que no se como conectar o inyectar las dependencias que necesito.

Asi tengo uno de los guards:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  CanActivate,
  CanMatch,
  Route,
  Router,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  UrlSegment,
  UrlTree,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, map, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PublicGuard implements CanMatch, CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  private checkAuthStatus(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.checkAuthStatus().pipe(
      tap((isAuth) => {
        console.log({ isAuth });
      }),
      tap((isAuthenticated) => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          this.router.navigate(['./']);
        }
      }),
      map((isAuthenticated) => !isAuthenticated)
    );
  }

  canMatch(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('canMatch');
    console.log({ route, segments });

    return this.checkAuthStatus();
  }
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('canActivate');
    console.log({ route, state });

    return this.checkAuthStatus();
  }
}
```

Asi tengo mi AuthService:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environments } from 'src/environments/environments';
import { User } from '../interfaces/user.interface';
import { Observable, catchError, map, of, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  private baseUrl = environments.baseUrl;
  private user?: User;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  get currentUser(): User | undefined {
    if (!this.user) return undefined;
    return structuredClone(this.user);
  }
  public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User>(`${this.baseUrl}/users/1`).pipe(
      tap((user) => (this.user = user)),
      tap((user) => localStorage.setItem('token', 'fdsfsdfsd.fsdfsd.fsdfds'))
    );
  }
  public checkAuthStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) return of(false);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return this.httpClient.get<User>(`${this.baseUrl}/users/1`).pipe(
      tap((user) => (this.user = user)),
      map((user) => !!user),
      catchError((error) => of(false))
    );
  }

  public logout() {
    this.user = undefined;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Y asi mi AppRouting:

```js
import { NgModule, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Error404PageComponent } from './shared/pages/error404-page/error404-page.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/guards/auth.guard';
import { PublicGuard } from './auth/guards/public.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./auth/auth.module').then((module) => module.AuthModule),
    canActivate: [PublicGuard],
    canMatch: [PublicGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'heros',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./heros/heros.module').then((module) => module.HerosModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canMatch: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: Error404PageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'heros',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Esta es la implementación que me sugieren los snippets:

```js
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivateFn, CanMatchFn, Route, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

export const PublicCanActivateGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
  return true;
};

export const PublicCanMatchGuard: CanMatchFn = (
  route: Route,
  segments: UrlSegment[]
) => {
  return true;
};
```

Según la documentación hay que hacer esto:

```js
const canMatchTeam: CanMatchFn = (route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
  return inject(PermissionsService).canMatch(inject(UserToken));
};
```

Si yo quisiera inyectar mi AuthService en estos guards como debería hacerlo, osea si quiero inyectar esa dependencia para usar uno de sus métodos?

Answer (score 0):

El código que compartiste está algo enredado y confuso, igual te comparto como usar Guards como funciones, prácticamente se repite el código así que tal vez puedas refactorizarlo.

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn, CanMatchFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const userService = inject(UserService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return userService.tokenValidation().pipe(
    tap((isAuthenticated) => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    })
  );
};

export const canMatch: CanMatchFn = () => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  const userService = inject(UserService);

  return userService.tokenValidation().pipe(
    tap((isAuthenticated) => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    })
  );
};
```

Por otro lado, en las otras partes del código tienes un montón de `tap`, `map`, etc. que sólo te va a confundir más y empeorará la legibilidad del código, mientras que en el `logout()` tienes `localStorage.clear()` lo cual elimina TODO, tal vez quieras usar `localStorage.remove('NOMBRE_DE_LO_QUE_QUIERAS_QUITAR')`, igual no olvides de agregar el código para manejar errores en `login`.